# Unable to load certificates when trying to generate pfx file

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have been struggling for the last three hours trying to create an .`pfx` file using `OpenSSL`.  I have been following this [document](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/) and have been following the instructions under the `Get a certificate using OpenSSL` header.

I am at the step here: `openssl pkcs12 -export -out myserver.pfx -inkey myserver.key -in myserver.crt` and am using the `OpenSSL.exe` console.

I get the error: `unable to load certificates`

I have also tried this: `x509 -text -in myserver.key` and received the error: `0906D06D06C:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.b.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`  I also get that error if I try myserver.crt.

I seem to get it no matter what I do.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Thanks.  I wish someone had told my boss at the time that it wasn't a programming or development topic and then I wouldn't have had all that pain ;)

Answer (score 31):

> I get the error: unable to load certificates

`myserver.crt` needs to be in PEM format. Does it have `----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----` and `----- END CERTIFICATE -----`?

---

`myserver.crt` should actually be a chain of certificates (and not just the one server certificate). The chain should include all intermediate certificates needed by the client to verify the chain.

You send all the intermediate certificates to solve the "which directory" problem. The "which directory" is a well know problem in PKI. Essentially, the client does not know where to go to fetch the missing intermediate cert. To avoid the problem, you send all intermediates.

I often use [Startcom](http://www.startcom.org/) because they offer free Class 1 certificates. When I get the signed server certificate from them (for example, www-example-com.crt), I add their Class 1 Server Intermediate to it. I get their Class 1 Server Intermediate from their website at [Startcom CA certs](https://www.startssl.com/certs/). The one I use is `sub.class1.server.ca.pem`.

With the `www-example-com.crt`, my server certificate looks like:

```
$ cat www-example-com.crt

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
< My Server Certificate >
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
< Startcom Intermediate >
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

For completeness, the private key (for example, `www-example-com.key`) is also in PEM format. It uses `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.

With my server certificate in PEM format (and with the required intermediates) and private key, I then issue the following (which looks like the same command you are using):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in www-example-com.crt -inkey www-example-com.key -out www-example-com.p12
```

When clients connect, they use the Startcom CA. So, to test the connection (after loading into IIS):

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -CAfile startcom-ca.pem
```

The command should complete with "Verify OK":

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 37E5AF0EE1745AB2...
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 7B9F8A79D3CC3A41...
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1243051912
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

---

> I have also tried this: x509 -text -in myserver.key and received the error...

`x509` is for certificates. If you want to dump a key, use OpenSSL's `pkey` command. See the docs on OpenSSL's [`pkey(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkey.html) command.

Comment: Thanks.  No they have --BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-- and --END PRIVATE KEY---

Comment: The argument to `-in` must be a certificate. You need a certificate, not a private key :)

Comment: OK, I'm confused.  My CA have given me a file like this for my crt: -----BEGIN PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA-----  what is this?  I'm using IIS.

Comment: `openssl pkcs7 -in file.pem -print_certs -out certs.pem`. I've never had to use the command, though. I've always gotten PEM or DER encoded certs. With a DER cert, I convert to PEM. The I perform the stuff above.

Comment: Thank you - telling me to find a version that had BEGIN CERTIFICATE and then END CERTIFICATE was what I needed. If you come to Newbury in the UK, I am buying you dinner.

Answer (score -1):

```
keytool -importcert -alias yourdns -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.15.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64/lib/security/cacerts -file  pathcertificate/.crc

password default = changeit
```